# Sending multiple model to single view generating Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I want to show the data form two different database table by using two model in one view. 
My EnrolmentWithCourses method **HomeController.cs**

```
public ActionResult EnrolmentWithCourses()
        {
            List<object> myModelCollection = new List<object>();

            myModelCollection.Add(db.Enrollments.ToList());
            myModelCollection.Add(db.Courses.ToList());
            return View(myModelCollection);
        }
```

My view **EnrolmentWithCourses.cshtml** is:

```
    @model IEnumerable<object>
    @{
        List<ContosoUniversity.Models.Course> CourseList = Model.ToList()[0] as List<ContosoUniversity.Models.Course>;
        List<ContosoUniversity.Models.Enrollment> EnrollmentList = Model.ToList()[1] as List<ContosoUniversity.Models.Enrollment>;  
    }
<h2>Course List</h2>
       @foreach (var item in CourseList)
        {
             <li> @item.CourseID </li>
             <li> @item.Title</li>

        }
    <h2>Course List</h2>
     @foreach (var item in EnrollmentList)
        {
             <li> @item.EnrollmentID</li>
             <li> @item.CourseID</li>
            <
        }
```

Comment: Use a view model with 2 properties `List<Course> CourseList` and `List<Enrollment> EnrollmentList`. Initialize it in the get methd, set the properties and pass it to the view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that  `Model.ToList()[0]` is a `List<ContosoUniversity.Models.Enrollment>` and not `List<ContosoUniversity.Models.Course>` because in your controller you add `db.Enrollments.ToList()` prior to `db.Courses.ToList()`:

```
List<object> myModelCollection = new List<object>();
myModelCollection.Add(db.Enrollments.ToList());
myModelCollection.Add(db.Courses.ToList());
return View(myModelCollection);
```

if you change the order it will work:

```
List<object> myModelCollection = new List<object>();
myModelCollection.Add(db.Courses.ToList());
myModelCollection.Add(db.Enrollments.ToList());    
return View(myModelCollection);
```

**BUT**
I strongly advice to create a stronglytyped model to avoid those kind of issue:

```
 public class YourModel
    {
       public IList<ContosoUniversity.Models.Enrollment> Enrollments {get;set}
       public IList<ContosoUniversity.Models.Course> Courses {get;set}
    }
```

Controller action will like:

```
public ActionResult EnrolmentWithCourses()
{
    var model = new YourModel{
        Enrollments = db.Enrollments.ToList(),
        Courses = db.Courses.ToList()
    };

    return View(model);
}
```

View

```
 @model YourModel

<h2>Course List</h2>
       @foreach (var item in Courses)
        {
             <li> @item.CourseID </li>
             <li> @item.Title</li>

        }
    <h2>Course List</h2>
     @foreach (var item in Enrollments)
        {
             <li> @item.EnrollmentID</li>
             <li> @item.CourseID</li>
            <
        }
```

Comment: oh Man.... you have saved my day ....:) :) :) You are 100% correct ....
I will try your next method ..... are you sure that's the best way .... ?.. What wrong with my method ??

Answer (score 1):

You should create a composite Model like as follows :

```
public class EnrolmentWithCoursesModel
{
     List<ContosoUniversity.Models.Course> CourseList {get; set; }
     List<ContosoUniversity.Models.Enrollment> EnrollmentList {get; set; }
}
```

Now change your action to return the composite Model for view :

```
public ActionResult EnrolmentWithCourses()
{
            EnrolmentWithCoursesModel myModelCollection = new EnrolmentWithCoursesModel() { CourseList = db.Courses.ToList(), EnrollmentList =  db.Enrollments.ToList() };

            return View(myModelCollection);
}
```

Now, your view should change to Model to make `EnrolmentWithCoursesModel`

```
 @model EnrolmentWithCoursesModel

<h2>Course List</h2>
       @foreach (var item in Model.CourseList)
        {
             <li> @item.CourseID </li>
             <li> @item.Title</li>

        }
    <h2>Course List</h2>
     @foreach (var item in Model.EnrollmentList)
        {
             <li> @item.EnrollmentID</li>
             <li> @item.CourseID</li>
            <
        }
```